# Merging overlapping date ranges with hierarchy in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to overlap date ranges according to a hierarchy of priority. I'm giving an example below. The below code

```
df = data.frame(Priority = c("Priority_2","Priority_1", "Priority_2"),
                Start = as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-08")),
                End = as.Date(c("2018-01-04","2018-01-05","2018-01-09")))
```

will provide you with this table:

```
Priority      Start        End
Priority_2    2018-01-01   2018-01-04
Priority_1    2018-01-03   2018-01-05
Priority_2    2018-01-08   2018-01-09
```

I'd like to be able to overlap date ranges, but according to some priority. The output table should look like this:

```
Priority      Start        End
Priority_2    2018-01-01   2018-01-02
Priority_1    2018-01-03   2018-01-05
NA            2018-01-06   2018-01-07
Priority_2    2018-01-08   2018-01-09
```

So, for example, if Priority_1 overlaps with any other priority, the date range is given to Priority_1. Otherwise, if Priority_2 overlaps with any other priority, the date range is given to Priority_2. If date ranges are unaccounted for, we get NA. I would also be ok if the output looked like this:

```
Priority      Start        End
Priority_2    2018-01-01   2018-01-03
Priority_1    2018-01-03   2018-01-05
NA            2018-01-05   2018-01-08
Priority_2    2018-01-08   2018-01-09
```

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one was surprisingly fun to work through (if you like puzzles). I'm interested to see what anyone else comes up with.

Let's do this with tidyverse only. Specifically `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `purrr`.

```
library(dplyr) # For dataframe functions
library(tidyr) # For nesting and fill functions
library(purrr) # For map functions
```

The first thing I'm going to do in the tidy framework is convert this to a more machine readable format. Specifically a long data format where each date is represented by it's own row. No more Start and End.

To get all the dates between Start and End let's use map2 to nest the sequence in a new column. I'm nesting this data because sometimes there is only 1 date, sometimes 3, sometimes ???. By nesting I can include all the dates in a single variable of the dataframe.

```
# Identify the all dates in the range and nest in a new column
df2 <- df %>%
  arrange(Start) %>%
  mutate(date = map2(Start,End,seq,by = 'day')) %>%
  select(-Start,-End)
```

> ```
>     Priority                       date
> 1 Priority_2 17532, 17533, 17534, 17535
> 2 Priority_1        17534, 17535, 17536
> 3 Priority_2               17539, 17540
> ```

Next I'm going to unnest the date row so that each date is its own row.

```
# Unnest the dates column so each item is a row
df2 <- df2 %>%
  unnest(date)
```

> ```
>     Priority       date
> 1 Priority_2 2018-01-01
> 2 Priority_2 2018-01-02
> 3 Priority_2 2018-01-03
> 4 Priority_2 2018-01-04
> 5 Priority_1 2018-01-03
> 6 Priority_1 2018-01-04
> 7 Priority_1 2018-01-05
> 8 Priority_2 2018-01-08
> 9 Priority_2 2018-01-09
> ```

Next, let's group by the date and summarize to pick the highest priority

```
# Now we can group_by each date! This means we can summarize to only
# select the highest priority
df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  # Min finds the lowest string. Priority_1 is lower than Priority_2 
  summarise(Priority = min(Priority))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 2
>   date       Priority  
>   <date>     <chr>     
> 1 2018-01-01 Priority_2
> 2 2018-01-02 Priority_2
> 3 2018-01-03 Priority_1
> 4 2018-01-04 Priority_1
> 5 2018-01-05 Priority_1
> 6 2018-01-08 Priority_2
> 7 2018-01-09 Priority_2
> ```

Shoot! Missing values. A simple full_join to all of the possible dates in the date range can fix that.

```
# Now for each date in the dataset we have only the highest priority
# but what about the missing values?
df2 <- df2 %>%
  # Join in a list of all days in the date range!
  full_join(tibble(date = seq(min(df$Start),max(df$End),by='day'))) %>%
  arrange(date)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 2
>   date       Priority  
>   <date>     <chr>     
> 1 2018-01-01 Priority_2
> 2 2018-01-02 Priority_2
> 3 2018-01-03 Priority_1
> 4 2018-01-04 Priority_1
> 5 2018-01-05 Priority_1
> 6 2018-01-06 NA        
> 7 2018-01-07 NA        
> 8 2018-01-08 Priority_2
> 9 2018-01-09 Priority_2
> ```

Now we need to figure out how to group back together spots where the same Priority happens multiple times in a row. If we turn `NA` values into `"NA"` we can use the lag function to see if a value is the same as the last value that occurred. This always returns NA for the first value (you can't see what occurred before the first value) so we need to fix that one small issue. Then we can use fill to fill in all the blanks.

```
# This is the data desired, but now it needs to be put back in the 
# human readable format it started in. Use lag to identify when Priority
# changes, then use fill to establish a group of the same Priority in a row.
df2 <- df2 %>%
  # Remove NA from Priority because it causes problems with !=
  replace_na(list(Priority = "NA")) %>%
  mutate(Group = ifelse(Priority != lag(Priority),1:n(),NA),
         # The first column will always be NA...so fix it.
         Group = ifelse(is.na(lag(Priority)),1,Group))%>%
  # Now that the breaks are identified, fill in the rest of the group 
  # with the most recent value
  fill(Group)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 3
>   date       Priority   Group
>   <date>     <chr>      <dbl>
> 1 2018-01-01 Priority_2  1.00
> 2 2018-01-02 Priority_2  1.00
> 3 2018-01-03 Priority_1  3.00
> 4 2018-01-04 Priority_1  3.00
> 5 2018-01-05 Priority_1  3.00
> 6 2018-01-06 NA          6.00
> 7 2018-01-07 NA          6.00
> 8 2018-01-08 Priority_2  8.00
> 9 2018-01-09 Priority_2  8.00
> ```

From here it is pretty quick to group by the `Priority` and `Group` columns, summarize to get the `Start` and `End` dates, and cleanup the variables.

```
# Return the data to human readable form using group_by and summarize
df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(Priority, Group) %>%
  summarise(Start = min(date),
            End = max(date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Return "NA" values to NA
  mutate(Priority = ifelse(Priority == "NA", NA, Priority)) %>%
  arrange(Start) %>%
  select(Priority,Start,End)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
>   Priority   Start      End       
>   <chr>      <date>     <date>    
> 1 Priority_2 2018-01-01 2018-01-02
> 2 Priority_1 2018-01-03 2018-01-05
> 3 NA         2018-01-06 2018-01-07
> 4 Priority_2 2018-01-08 2018-01-09
> ```

Or...the whole code in one pipedream

```
# Performing the whole thing in one go...
df3 <- df %>%
  arrange(Start) %>%
  mutate(date = map2(Start,End,seq,by = 'day')) %>%
  select(-Start,-End) %>%
  unnest(date) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(Priority = min(Priority))  %>%
  full_join(tibble(date = seq(min(df$Start),max(df$End),by='day'))) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  replace_na(list(Priority = "NA")) %>%
  mutate(Group = ifelse(Priority != lag(Priority),1:n(),NA),
         # The first column will always be NA...so fix it.
         Group = ifelse(is.na(lag(Priority)),1,Group)) %>%
  fill(Group) %>%
  group_by(Priority, Group) %>%
  summarise(Start = min(date),
            End = max(date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Priority = ifelse(Priority == "NA", NA, Priority)) %>%
  arrange(Start) %>%
  select(Priority,Start,End)
```

Comment: Well done this solved my problem. It is a surprisingly tricky task to accomplish. I'm actually working with date times, but was able to modify your code a bit so it would work for that. One question - you used min(Priority) to set the priorities. How can we modify this so that it would still work with more than 2 priorities? Say, Priority_1 > Priority_2 > Priority_3?

Comment: Two ways. First, `min(c("Priority_2","Priority_1","Priority_3"))` will return "Priority_1". `min(c("Priority_3","Priority_2","Priority_3"))` will return "Priority_2", and so on. It is just checking the string alphabetically.

Comment: Second options is to convert "Priority_#" string to a number. The stringr package can do that pretty easily. `mutate(num_priority = as.numeric(str_extract(Priority,"\\d+")))

Comment: If this solution is the best one you get please feel free to accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers